# Ignore certain .js files with webpack dev server running --hot

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-loader

I have the need to import some javascript files as pure text with webpack.

All the files have a specific extension say: `.mytype.js`.

I have created a loader for these files using:

```
module.loaders = [{
  test: /\.mytype.js?$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|public\/)/,
  loader: "mytype-loader"
}, ....]
```

I have regstered an alias to resolve my own loader

```
resolveLoader : {
  alias : {
    'mytype-loader' : path.resolve(__dirname, 'myloader.js')  
  }
}
```

At the moment `myloader.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = source => {
  console.log(source)
  return(source)
}
```

For my dev server I have the following setup:

```
   devServer: {

  watchOptions : {

    // I THOUGHT THIS WOULD STOP HOTLOAD CODE BEING ADDED??!
    ignored : path.resolve(__dirname, 'mytypeFiles')
  },

  contentBase: CONTENT_BASE,
  noInfo: true,
  hot: true,
  inline: true,

  port: PORT,
  headers : { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:8888'},
  host: HOST
  },
```

All of my files with extension `.mytype.js` are in the `mytypeFiles` directory. The problem is that when I run this I get the following output from the loaders `console.log`

```
'use-strict';

function run(args, resources, meta) {
     // a bunch of my code

}
;

var _temp = function () {
    if (typeof __REACT_HOT_LOADER__ === 'undefined') {
            return;
    }

    __REACT_HOT_LOADER__.register(run, 'run', 'D:/manatee-latest/manatee/src/bandicoot/resource-api/bandicoot-functions/run.bandicoot.js');
}();
```

However `use-strict`; and everything after the first function definition (which is mine) has been attached. How do I stop this hot loader code from being pre & post-fixed to my source?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW - temporarily getting around this with a horrible rexexp.

Comment: Have you find a proper solution since February?

Comment: I guess the watchOptions didn't work because this is using --hot instead of watch.

Comment: Seems like that is not possible, need to fork the lib. This problem forced me to disable HMR in my project because of use specific vendors.